# Update new inserted record through trigger in a same table of oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-trigger

Update new inserted record through trigger in a same table of oracle.

```
-------CODE----------
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Update_CCID
AFTER INSERT
   ON XXAW.XXAW_AR_INV_STG_T_TEST
   referencing OLD as old NEW as new 
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    If :new.Account_Name like '%.VAT%'
    then
        :new.segment2 := '000';
        :new.segment4 := '000';
        :new.segment5 := '622';
    end if;
END ;
-------------------------------
```

I am getting below error:

```
[Error] PLS-00103 (8: 29): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LIKE" when expecting one of the following:
not null of nan infinite dangling a empty
```

Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't modify :NEW values in an AFTER trigger - should be BEFORE. Besides, there's nothing wrong with "like" so - are you sure you posted accurate code?

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (account_name varchar2(20), segment2 varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_test
  2    after insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if :new.account_name like '%.VAT%' then
  6       :new.segment2 := '000';
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /
create or replace trigger trg_test
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type


SQL> l2
  2*   after insert on test
SQL> c/after/before
  2*   before insert on test
SQL> l
  1  create or replace trigger trg_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if :new.account_name like '%.VAT%' then
  6       :new.segment2 := '000';
  7    end if;
  8* end;
SQL> /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use Virtual Columns while creating table. An alternate expression is used for `segment4` because a table can't have same expression for 2 virtual column

```
create  table XXAW.XXAW_AR_INV_STG_T_TEST
(

  Account_Name VARCHAR2(10),
  segment2 VARCHAR2(10)  AS ( CASE WHEN Account_Name like '%.VAT%' THEN '000'  END ), 
  segment4 VARCHAR2(10)  AS ( CASE WHEN INSTR(Account_Name,'.VAT') > 0  THEN '000'  END ),
  segment5 VARCHAR2(10)  AS ( CASE WHEN Account_Name like '%.VAT%' THEN '622'  END ) 

);
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6871eb/1)

Only drawback is you may not insert or update on these columns directly. Otherwise, it will throw
`ORA-54013` and `ORA-54017`